# afnetworking confusing

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I have some code like this:
In a `viewcontroller`, I have a `table view` and a `scrollview`(some buttons on there),
In the table view cell :

```
-(void) setImageOfImageView: (NSURL *) _imageURL
{
    [_imageView setImageWithURL:_imageURL 
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"document-placeHolder-Image.png"]];
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

And the buttons are like this:

```
for(...)
{
    _request = ....;
    _buttonRequestOperation=[AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:_request
   imageProcessingBlock:nil
   success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) 
{
 //create an uibutton,use the image for background
}
     failure:nil];
    [[[self class] sharedButtonRequestOperationQueue] addOperation:_buttonRequestOperation];
}
```

Image in the table view cell sometimes show the button image,and the button show the image of table view cell.
Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Are you reseting the cell properties when you dequeue them for reuse?

Comment: Yes,I think the problem is the second code.The tableviewcell works well when i comment the second code,But i don't know what's the problem.

Comment: When are you calling ``setImageOfImageView``? Are you sure that you have the image downloaded when you call that method?